# varying responsiveness of official raspberry pi 7 inch touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

I bought 2 official Raspberry Pi 7 inch Touchscreens and 2 Raspberry Pi +3B devices. 
I connected everything and the screens are working, most of the time.

But about 1 out of 10 clicks/touches on the screen is not registered by the screen/pi. The mouse-pointer does not move and nothing happened. 
This especially happens when touching/clicking at a faster (but reasonable) rate. 
This is very annoying.

Does anybody know a solution? The issue appears on both screens.
Both Pi's are running Raspbian Stretch 9.
Any help or suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: at the person who gave this a "+1" => do you have the same problem?